# Cannot seem to write to usb drive using pi user

Tags: usb, mount

Really simple problem, I have run the following commands:

```
sudo mkdir /media/usb
sudo chown -R pi:pi /media/usb
show chmod -R 775 /media/usb
```

Checked everything and made sure that `pi` owned the directory, and then ran:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/usb -o uid=pi,gid=pi
```

The drive is `ext4` and if I `sudo` it works (I can write to it) but I cannot seem to get it to work so `pi` can write without, because when I run the above the command it will reset all permissions to root.

I also cannot seem to get it to auto mount as `pi`.

I have eve install `ntfs-3g` incase that made any effect, but every time only root can write.

Here is the output of mounting:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/media $ sudo umount usb
pi@raspberrypi:/media $ ls -la
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4096 Sep 21 13:12 .
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root 4096 Jun 27 02:22 ..
drwxr-x---+  4 root root 4096 Sep 21 14:24 pi
drwxrwxr-x   2 pi   pi   4096 Sep 21 13:12 usb
pi@raspberrypi:/media $ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/usb -o uid=1000,gid=1000
pi@raspberrypi:/media $ cd usb
pi@raspberrypi:/media/usb $ ls -la
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root  4096 Sep 21 14:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Sep 21 13:12 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Sep 21 14:24 dfgfdh
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Sep 21 14:18 f
drwx------ 2 root root 16384 Sep 21 11:45 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Sep 21 14:23 swedtfr
pi@raspberrypi:/media/usb $
```

With options switched:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/media $ sudo mount -o uid=1000,gid=1000 /dev/sda1 /media/usb
pi@raspberrypi:/media $ cd usb
pi@raspberrypi:/media/usb $ ls -la
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root  4096 Sep 21 14:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Sep 21 13:12 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Sep 21 14:24 dfgfdh
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Sep 21 14:18 f
drwx------ 2 root root 16384 Sep 21 11:45 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Sep 21 14:23 swedtfr
```

Comment: I don't think it's useful chown'ing and chmod'ing before the mount.

Comment: I have seen other guides do it. Since changing the auto mount point to pi user it now will mount as pi user to usb folder

Comment: I suspect the reason is that because it's an ext4 (linux) drive you are mounting that you can't just ignore the permissions on the folders and files on the USB drive. Executing chown and chmod on the mountpoint before you mount it won't make the file permission on the drive change when it mounts.  You could maybe chown and chmod  recursively on the drive after it has been mounted - this will reset the permission on the all files on the drive though - so if you are using it on multiple machines this won't be ideal.

Comment: @Charemer even `.` comes under this problem, so it isn't a problem that recursive chown can solve

Comment: Why do you use `/media` and not `/mnt`?

Comment: @Sammaye in the listing `.` is the root of the usb drive itself that can only be listed once the drive is mounted.  unmount it and run ls -l on /media/usb, you'll find that `.` has the permissions you have set.

Comment: @Fabian because raspian uses it

Comment: @Charemer the drive is mounted in the example there that you can see directly from my terminal

Comment: @Charemer to clarify, certain folers like the fs lost+found should be root, but ignore those other root folders, the only one that matter is the permissions on the usb mount folder itself, `.`

Comment: @Sammaye  I think you misunderstood.  When the drive is mounted :  `pi@raspberrypi:/media/usb $ ls -la` `.` is the root of the mounted drive and has  the permission of the root of that drive.  When the drive in not mounted `.` is the local filesystem /media/usb folder and has the permissions you gave it. - unmount the drive and create a file in `/media/usb` and list it.  Then mount the drive and again list `/media/usb`  - the file is not visible.  Any files at a mount point are hidden by the  mounted fileystem and that includes `.`.

Comment: @Charemer I understand that fully, but I am unsure how your comment really helps this question, can you clarify? I am trying to modify the permissions on the mounted drive folder, which in this case is `.`, since the drive is mounted (as you illustrated with your file there/not there paradigm), normally this would be achieved with `mount` user options but that doesn't work, another thread I saw said to change the actual file mount folder, but that doesn't work either. I found that changing the automount folder perrmissions in `/media/pi` does work and replicates the permission to mount folder

Comment: @Charemer so it seems as though Raspian is actually overriding whatever options I put into `mount` and replacing them with the permissions on the automount folder in `/media/pi`, not sure if this is debian so I said raspian

Comment: For further information check the two top answers here for  information on permissions for mounted linux filesystems https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181260/ownership-of-a-mount-point particularly the 2nd answer from Hildred.

Comment: @Charemer the first two answers there state that changing the permission on `.` should work

Comment: @Charemer it might be I have to chown when it is actually mounted, but other threads would state that is not the case nor the correct way to do it and that thread even has a comment below one answer to say this should happen when unmounted since mount will apply its own permission set each time

Comment: " you do not need to set the uid on any filesystem that was designed for unix, Indeed you do not want to, as the filesystem can do this itself" - and does using the permissions of the filesystem being mounted.

Comment: @Charemer but the file system has no permissions, when I first mounted this it was a freshly formatted disk with zero user permissions

Comment: @Sammaye - formatted by? ....(root - you'd either have to be root or use sudo to create the filesystem)  An ext4 filesystem cannot be 'with zero user permissions'.

Comment: @Charemer ok that inspired a search that did actually return a result, if I `chmod` the `/dev/` mount of it then it will work, you don't `chmod` the `media`/`mnt` instance but the actual mount itself

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the uid of pi is 1001, and the gid of pi's group is 201, you'd use

```
sudo mount  -o uid=1001,gid=201 /dev/sda1 /media/usb
```

You need to pass the id's, not the names, and the options go before device and mount point.

Let me give you an example:

```
ghp-amdphIIX4B:/root
# id ghp
UID=1000(ghp) GID=1000(ghp)
ghp-amdphIIX4B:/root
# mount -o uid=1000,gid=1000 /dev/sdc1 /mnt/sdc1
ghp-amdphIIX4B:/root
# ls -al /mnt/sdc1
totaal 9087532
drwxr-xr-x  4 ghp  ghp        8192 jan  1  1970 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root       4096 aug 11 16:15 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ghp  ghp          21 jan  1  1980 .cm0013
drwxr-xr-x  3 ghp  ghp        8192 aug 11 16:17 Jennifer
drwxr-xr-x  2 ghp  ghp        8192 jun 11  2017 System Volume Information
```

One difference, my usb stick contains a vfat.

Comment: I guess you could include your comment on the question in your answer as it seems to be related to the overall procedure.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe there's no need for the chmod and chown.  Hope to hear from the OP.

Comment: Done that, same result

Comment: Can you add the output from "ls -al /media/usb" (after the mount) to your question?

Comment: Done, you can see even using the UID and GID directly, though don't really need to

Comment: Edited my answer, the options go before device and mountpoint.

Comment: Same result, puitting the options at start or at end results in same result

Comment: Normally Linux commands do not care form order, they parse it all the same, only for unnamed options they care

Comment: device and dir are "unnamed", and the man page puts the options first.

Comment: If I chown the auto mount point it will actually make usb folder pi

Comment: but -o is parsed, and that's options

Comment: Added the result of options at start to my question

Comment: I actually cannot use vfat here, the file allocation size is too small, so I can't use the example, but vfat, unlike filesystems that support bigger files, is user-less

Comment: I'm looking for a stick with ext4.

Comment: I'm also on a Pi 3 B+ with latest distro version

Comment: When I try to mount an ext4 with "-o uid=...,gid=..." I get "mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock".

Comment: So, the only option is "chown -R" after mounting.

Comment: Really? Hmm, I don't get such errors, are you sure it is formatted as ext4? Normally that is a low level error, one which basically says "either you don't know your disk formatting or this disk is broken, buddy"

Comment: Without options, mount succeeds, shows ext4.